# Python XML-RPC <struct> data type

Tags: python, xml, xml-rpc

I'm having problem with  data type in python.
I run `system.methodSignature('SearchInfo')`, it returns [['array', 'struct']].
What should I put as the argument in `SearchInfo()`? 
And what is struct data type in xml-rpc?

Please help.

Comment: What library is this?

Comment: it's in the xmlrpc library

Comment: I believe that you should mark your answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out the way for `<struct>` data type for xmlrpc.
 data type is like a dict type.

For my case, it's actually `SearchInfo({'id' : 12345})`.

Good luck to whoever needing this information (: